# How to calculate p-value when comparing the percentage similarity of matrices in R

Tags: r, p-value

My question is derived from a previous topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77287721/how-to-compare-several-matrices-and-calculate-the-percentage-difference-in-r/77287785#77287785
, where @ThomasIsCoding provided the excellent and simple answer.

Now I need to calculate the statistical significance, that is, the p-value of how different the matrices are.

data

```
set.seed(0)
nrow <- 4
ncol <- 5
m1 <- matrix(rbinom(nrow * ncol, 1, .5), nrow, ncol)
m2 <- matrix(rbinom(nrow * ncol, 1, .5), nrow, ncol)
m3 <- matrix(rbinom(nrow * ncol, 1, .5), nrow, ncol)

lst <- list(m1, m2, m3)

1 - adist(unlist(lapply(lst, toString))) / lengths(lst)
```

and the result

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.5  0.4
[2,]  0.5  1.0  0.5
[3,]  0.4  0.5  1.0
```

It is important for me to understand how statistically significant the differences between the matrices are. I think because matrix data in its original form is binary, that is, each matrix on real data consists of 0 and 1 and that’s it.
I think that perhaps we should use the `chi-square` test when comparing matrices. But I don’t understand how.
I see deserid output like that.

```
       [1-2]    [1-3]   [2-3]
p-value 0,01    0,02    0,03
```

where digits are number of matrix. For example 1 is `m1`.

Are there any ways to calculate p-value in the context of comparing matrices consisting of binary values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the data you want to analyse is like the data you've synthesised, that is, a bernoulli process, I think you can use a simple binomial test.

Imagine you have two coins. You've tested them on their own, and they seem like completely normal, fair coins. But when you flip both at the same time it feels like they're connected. They both still show heads and tails equally often, but more frequently than expected, they show the same face. The number of times they show the same face (success) follows a binomial distribution, in our case $\operatorname{Binomial}(20, 0.5)$. We can use this to quantify how unlikely a certain number of successes are if the two bernoulli processes are equally distributed, but unrelated, i.e. the p-value. The fact that your data is arranged in matrices shouldn't make any difference.

```
set.seed(0)
nrow <- 4
ncol <- 5

lst <- replicate(3, matrix(rbinom(nrow*ncol, 1, .5), nrow), simplify=FALSE)

eg <- expand.grid(1:length(lst), 1:length(lst))
sim <- apply(eg, 1, function(x) sum(lst[[x[1]]] == lst[[x[2]]]))
sim <- matrix(sim, length(lst))
simp <- sim/(nrow*ncol)

pva <- sapply(sim, function(x) binom.test(x, nrow*ncol)$p.val)
pva <- matrix(pva, length(lst))

# Similarity
simp
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  1.0  0.5  0.4
# [2,]  0.5  1.0  0.5
# [3,]  0.4  0.5  1.0

# P-value on similarities
print(pva, digits=2)
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 0.0000019 1.0000000 0.5034447
# [2,] 1.0000000 0.0000019 1.0000000
# [3,] 0.5034447 1.0000000 0.0000019
```

As you can see, the matrices are compared cell by cell, if they match it's a success, if they don't its a fail, and the successes are summed. The number of successes is the basis for the (two-tailed) binomial test and the p-value is extracted. Notice there is no [multiple comparison correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem). If it isn't safe to assume equally distributed bernoulli precesses, you should probably write a new question.